# Can't search profile in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, profile, search, search-results, individual

I have created a new profile in CiviCRM that I want to use for searches of services offered by associate members. When I test the profile from CiviCRM it behaves as expected. If I embed the profile in a WordPress page, I get no results. When I submit the form, I just return to my profile search form.

When I open the console on the page, I get the following error:
{}ExtensionContent.jsm
Error: Incorrectcontentsfetched,
pleasereload.

Comment: What version of civicrm are you running?

Comment: Version 5.20.1 currently.

Comment: And you are "embedding" using a shortcode?

Comment: Yes, I’m using the short code and I’ve tried with and without the page contents override. Ideally, I’d like to provide some instruction for using the form in Wordpress page, but I can enter it from CiviCRM if I must. It’s an aesthetic choice.

Comment: Thank you for the help. We just figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution is a total head slapper. The problem was caused by previewing the page instead of publishing the page and viewing the published content. The directory profile is working.